# How to resize table columns width when it takes a browse field

Tags: html, css

in a table field i am taking input as a file.

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>
<input type="file" name="icon" id="icon" />
</th> 
</tr>
</table>
```

It takes a size a 242-246px as width.

I declare :

```
<th width="50px"><input type="file" name="icon" id="icon" /></th>
```

But no changes occurred as size. Have any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to decrease column size if it contain an object

You have file object. If its width is 100px then column will be in => 100 px.
You can increase size but not decrease...

Comment: here is a link it may help       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197835/resize-the-input-type-file-browse-button-in-firefox

Answer (score 0):

helo  its not clear what you did and what you want...
 i assume u want to change the size.
   then add that attribute to table first.
th is header do you want to resize the word 'icon' then use font tag

Comment: No actually I want to change a table column width. that column contains browse button for icon. But I cannot change the size of this column.

Comment: better choice is to use colspan or if you change width all coloms will increase width

Comment: I also used it but no change occurred.

Comment: are you try to resize file browse icon.you cant decrease size of colom if it contain any objects.object width is default..

Comment: just realize ..... When I am inputing  a file then in the field a "Browse" button apper. This Browse button takes a default size perhaps, this the column side is not changed.

Comment: Cant find any idea to re size it.

Comment: how much width you... want and howmuch is currently

Comment: I already mention in question , it takes bydeafult 242-246 px, but I wat 50 px @aovbros

Comment: yes thats the problem....you try to set 50px.but "file browse" object will have 254..px width.its assigned by web browser creator.its cant resize..but here a chance to do a bit... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197835/resize-the-input-type-file-browse-button-in-firefox